# Why both immutable and mutable list objects are changed, when I change only the values of the mutable list?

Tags: list, kotlin, filter

We have a data class:

```
data class TestObject(
val param1: String,
val param2: String,
var param3: Int?)
```

and the following code:

```
    val obj1 = TestObject(
    param1 = "aaa",
    param2 = "aaa",
    param3 = null
)
val obj2 = TestObject(
    param1 = "aaa",
    param2 = "bbb",
    param3 = null
)
val obj3 = TestObject(
    param1 = "ccc",
    param2 = "bbb",
    param3 = null
)


val immutableList: List<TestObject> = listOf(obj1, obj2, obj3)

val changeableList = mutableListOf<TestObject>()

val testExercise1 = immutableList.filter { it.param1 == "aaa" }.random()
changeableList.add(0, testExercise1 )

val testExercise2 = immutableList.filter { it.param2 == "bbb" }.random()
changeableList.add(1, testExercise2 )

changeableList[0].param3 = 55
changeableList[1].param3 = 66
```

For some reason, when the param3 of the changeableList objects is changed, the param3 of the immutableList is changed as well. Why is this happening?

I want the immutableList to stay as it was defined in the beginning, and only change the changeableList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because at no point is Kotlin making a copy of your `TestObject`s.  When you create an immutable list, you're making an immutable holder of your mutable `TestObject` type -- and if you change the underlying `TestObject`s, they'll change everywhere.

To address this, when you make a copy of the list, you will need to add `.map { it.copy() }` -- or, better, just make `TestObject` immutable in the first place.

Comment: I think List shouldn't be referred to as "immutable" at all. It is *read-only*. The interface makes no promise that the contents won't change, and there is a fairly common pattern in Kotlin and in Android documentation of exposing a read-only SharedFlow/List/LiveData *view* of a mutating MutableSharedFlow/MutableList/MutableLiveData instance. Notably, in the case of SharedFlow and LiveData, these classes would be useless if they actually were immutable.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman, thanks so much for the answer. I was trying 5 hours to find wtf was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Louis for the answer. Just to add the correct code:

```
    val testExercise1 = immutableList.map { it.copy() }.filter { it.param1 == "aaa" }.random()
changeableList.add(0, testExercise1)

val testExercise2 = immutableList.map { it.copy() }.filter { it.param2 == "bbb" }.random()
changeableList.add(1, testExercise2)
```